# Running android got error like this "unresolved supertypes: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej"

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

Error message after run android kotlin: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath: class com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage, unresolved supertypes: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej

I use firebase gradle as below

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.2'
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.2'
```

Here my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ig.pipayalipayalliance.android"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 20
        versionName "1.4.9 UAT"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    configurations {
        all {
            exclude module: 'httpclient'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/aidl']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'
    // Multidex
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    // Rx
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    // Data binding
//    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0-alpha05'
    // Anko Commons
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
    // Network connection
    compile 'com.github.TuonBondol:NetworkUtil:1.0.2'
    // Keyboard
    compile 'com.github.TuonBondol:KeyboardUtil:1.0.1'
    // Image loading
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
    // Detect keyboard status
    compile 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.2'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.2'
    // Generate qr code
    compile 'com.github.SumiMakito:AwesomeQRCode-Kotlin:1.0.5'
    compile files('libs/pushservice20140827.jar')
    //Round image plugin
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:1.9.2'
    // infinite scroll
    compile 'com.github.tuonbondol:Android-RecyclerView-Infinitescroll:1.0.5'

    //load image
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use latest version of those libraries like below and you have replace `compile` with `implementation`

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1"
```

You have to update all firebase libraries with Google Play service. This is old enough.

Besides this you should have used only specific google play service instead of bundled one.

Comment: I have tried but got results ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.0.0 .

Comment: @ChuobBunthoeurn set `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'`

Comment: Ok, let me try. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

It could be a ProGuard issue. I can't post a full solution right now, but you can google how to instruct ProGuard to keep Firebase classes. I'll update later if I can.

Comment: Could you help me please? Right now I'm about stuck with this issue.